# How to grant a user SSRS browser permissions on a folder without giving them access to the root

Tags: reporting-services, permissions, ssrs-2017

When users browse to http://ssrs_server/reports, they get access denied unless they have Browser permission on the root folder. If they have Browser on folder Dept_1_Reports, they can browse successfully to http://ssrs_server/Reports/browse/Dept_1_Reports though. This is not a great user experience as they will not have a way to get to their reports with knowing the folder name. Granting Browser permission on the root folder is a big security problem as any new folders will inherit this permission, inadvertently granting users access to reports that they should not have. This seems like a design flaw - the 'landing page' of SSRS should show the user all folders that they have access to and show them. Am I missing something? This is SSRS 2017

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this, almost...

I had a similar situation but now have a setup where users can see all folders but cannot see reports within those folders unless authorised.

The trick is to create a new role.

I called mine 'FolderBrowserOnly'

To do this, open SSMS, connect to your Reporting Services Server

[image]

Expand the security folder and roles folder, then add a new role.

[image]

Set the properties so the role only has 'View Folders' permissions.

[image]

Now go back to your SSRS portal, go to the root folder and choose manage folder from the menu.

Set the user(s) role to 'FolderBrowserOnly' as required.

[image]

You can then set the normal 'Browser' role for specific users in specific folders.

There may be a better way of doing this but this worked for me.

**Note** This was done using SSRS 2016 but I think it will be very similar for 2017