# SQL Server 2014 Reporting Services : hiding a menu

Tags: reporting-services

SSRS 2014, on the report portal website: how do I hide the menu bar circled in red on the attached screenshot? When I send a report URL to a user, I do not want to give them the ability to click on and navigate to any of the parent folders.

[SSRS-Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQKsJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious solution would be to setup security on your reports so users cannot access the other reports, but in answer to your question, you can use the following format.

```
http://myservername/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMYREPORTFOLDER%2fMYREPORTNAME&rs:Command=Render
```

notice that we use `/ReportServer/` rather than the usual `/Reports/`

Comment: Thank you for the reply!  I tried adding &rs:Command=Render to the end of the report's URL, but the menu bar was still there.  I do have security setup on all the reports, I just don't want the users seeing and then submitting requests for access to reports that don't pertain to them.  Thanks again!

Comment: The important bit is the `ReportServer` rather than `Reports` in the URL. Edit your question and show the URL you are using if this does not help. As for the security. The answer is rather long so you should probably ask a new question. I think I answered a similar question some time back. If I can find that I'll add a comment with a link but basically you set everyone up as a folder browser (a new role you have to create) and then only specific users are added to specific folders/report.

Comment: Found it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65706212/how-to-grant-a-user-ssrs-browser-permissions-on-a-folder-without-giving-them-acc/65706888#65706888

Comment: That did it!  Changing Reports to ReportServer in the URL removed that menu.  Good job!  Thank you!!