I would like to hide the 'Home' navigation at the Folder level in Reporting Services
I need to allow access to the reports in a Reporting Services Folder.  I need to prevent navigation to other folders.  I need to hide the 'Home' option.
I have already tried 'rc:Toolbar=false' and 'rv:Toolbar=false'
I have tried:
http://servername/Reports/browse/3E_Audit_Letters&rv:Toolbar=false
also when I use 'ReportServer' the reports are shown as text and not Icons.

Use a role that only has rights to browse folders, apply to all users, then assign specific folder rights (Role=Browser) to each user. You can't get rid of the Home link out of the box and users will be able to see folders, but nothing inside the folder unless they have specific access. See this post for details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65706212

Thank you.  Let me clarify the situation.  Unfortunately, the users in question have full access to all folders in Reporting Services.  This allows them to click hyperlinks to see sub-reports.  Up to this point, this worked because they are not given a link to the RS server. All reports are scheduled and emailed.  There is a new Committee which they are part of that needs to be able to run 2 reports ad-hoc.  If the Home navigation cannot be hidden at the folder level, I will send links directly to the 2 reports and have them save as favorites.

I'm not sure I fully understand the scenario but you should be able to remove the browser role at the root level for all affected users, then create the new role (as par my answer linked above) and assign then the new "Folder Browser" role. You can then give them access just to the folder(s) you want. You could create a new folder have have the 2 reports linked in there and just give them browser role rights to the new folder.
